# Operador de Junção Union

Tags: sql, postgresql

Preciso apresentar os departamentos que tiveram movimentação de estoque em fev/2018 e os que tiveram em mar/2018. Preciso usar um operador de união para mostrar os resultados das duas consultas cada uma delas retornando os departamentos de um mês. Em cada consulta devo evitar departamentos repetidos. Preciso mostrar o código e nome do departamento ordenando pelo código do mesmo.
Essa tabela aqui de baixo é a tabela de movimentação de estoque (MOVESTOQUE)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha tabela dos departamentos (DEPARTAMENTO) é essa:
CODDEP 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
DESCRICAO Vendas (1), Compras(2), TI(3), Gerência(4), Almoxarifado(5), Diretoria(6), Financeiro(7), Estoque(8), Atendimento ao Cliente(9)

O CODDEP é uma coluna e a DESCRICAO é outra coluna.

Comment: Não consegui entender a pergunta. Primeiro, qual é o banco de dados? MySQL, Postgree, Oracle? "Preciso usar um operador de união para mostrar os resultados das duas consultas cada uma delas retornando os departamentos de um mês." Como assim? Se os resultados estão todos na mesma tabela não é necessário realizar nenhuma união, trata-se só de refinamento de código.

Comment: Olá. O DB é o Postgress. A pergunta original que tenho que resolver é essa: " Apresente os departamentos que tiveram movimentação de estoque em fev/2018 e os que tiveram em mar/2018. Usar um operador de união para mostrar os resultados das duas consultas cada uma delas retornando os departamentos de um mês. Em cada consulta, devem ser evitados departamentos repetidos. Mostrar código e nome do departamento ordenando pelo código do mesmo."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct
coddep,
dthora

from
movestoque

where
dthora between '2018-02-01' and '2018-02-28'

UNION

select distinct
coddep,
dthora

from
movestoque

where
dthora between '2018-03-01' and '2018-03-31'
```

Comment: Shoow!! Com esse exemplo consigo resolver as próximas duas questões. Brigadão ae Rodrigo!!